# Summarise after using pivot_wider

Tags: r, dplyr, tidyr

I am trying to perform a basic group by using the `pivot_wider` in `tidyr`. What I am looking for is the *average ratings between business travelers and tourists*. But, I encounter the following error:

```
Error: Problem with `mutate()` input `for_business`.
x invalid 'labels'; length 2 should be 1 or 1
i Input `for_business` is `factor(for_business, labels = c("business", "tourist"))`.
i The error occurred in group 2: property_id = 1002.
```

My code:

```
library(tidyverse)

bookings <- read_csv("bookings.csv")

bookings %>%
  group_by(property_id, for_business) %>%
  summarize(avg_review_score = mean(review_score, na.rm = TRUE)) %>%
  mutate(for_business = factor(for_business, labels = c("business", "tourist"))) %>%
  mutate(diff = business - tourist) %>%
  pivot_wider(names_from = for_business, values_from = avg_review_score) %>%
  summarize(avg_diff = mean(diff, na.rm = TRUE)) %>%
ungroup()
```

output of `dput(head(bookings))`

```
> dput(head(bookings))
structure(list(booker_id = c("215934017ba98c09f30dedd29237b43dad5c7b5f", 
"7f590fd6d318248a48665f7f7db529aca40c84f5", "10f0f138e8bb1015d3928f2b7d828cbb50cd0804", 
"7b55021a4160dde65e31963fa55a096535bcad17", "6694a79d158c7818cd63831b71bac91286db5aff", 
"d0358740d5f15e85523f94ab8219f25d8c017347"), property_id = c(2668L, 
4656L, 4563L, 4088L, 2188L, 4171L), room_nights = c(4L, 5L, 6L, 
7L, 4L, 2L), price_per_night = c(91.4669561442773, 106.504997616816, 
86.9913739625713, 92.3656155139053, 104.838941902747, 109.981876495045
), checkin_day = c("mon", "tue", "wed", "fri", "tue", "fri"), 
    for_business = c(FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE
    ), status = c("cancelled", "cancelled", "stayed", "stayed", 
    "stayed", "cancelled"), review_score = c(NA, NA, 6.25812265672399, 
    5.953597754693, 6.43474489539585, NA)), row.names = c(NA, 
6L), class = "data.frame")
```

Comment: in the dput `for_business` is actually a logical variable!! so why are you trying to convert it into a factor?

Comment: In next step there is another error! there are no variables named `business` and `tourist` so how `diff` will be calculated?  What you are actually trying to do here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You haven't shared enough data but you can try :

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)

bookings %>%
  group_by(property_id, for_business) %>%
  summarize(avg_review_score = mean(review_score, na.rm = TRUE)) %>%
  ungroup %>%
  mutate(for_business = c("tourist", "business")[for_business + 1]) %>%
  pivot_wider(names_from = for_business, values_from = avg_review_score) %>%
  mutate(diff = business - tourist) %>%
  summarize(avg_diff = mean(diff, na.rm = TRUE))
```

Comment: Yep, it works but your output is giving me a value `-0.573` , however, I used as `mutate(for_business = factor(for_business, labels = c("business", "tourist"))) %>%` it is giving me `0.573`. So I have a question that can this average be negative? Is that the extra info you are looking for?

Comment: It is because I am assigning `TRUE` to 'business' and `FALSE` to `tourist` and I guess you are doing the opposite. Overall it does not matter if you take absolute value of the difference with `abs`.